# How can I parameterize access to a Java enum in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

Say I have a Java enum. For example:

```
public enum Suits {CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES};
```

Normally, I can do something in clojure with that enum like so:

```
(defn do-something []
   (let [s Suits/DIAMONDS] (...)))
```

But, I want to write a clojure function that allows the caller to specify which enum instance to use:

```
(defn do-something-parameterized [suit]
   (let [s  Suits/suit] (...)))
```

The idea is to let a caller pass in `"DIAMONDS"` and have the `DIAMONDS` enum instance get bound to `s` in the `let`.

I could have a `cond` match against the parameter but that seems clunkier than necessary. I suppose I could also use a macro to construct `Suits/` added to `suit`. Is this the way to do it or is there a non-macro way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need for reflection or maps. Every Java enum has a static `valueOf` method that retrieves an enum value by name. So:

```
(defn do-something-parameterized [suit]
  (let [s (Suit/valueOf (name suit))] ...))
```

Using `(name)` allows either strings or keywords to be used:

```
(do-something-parameterized "HEARTS")
(do-something-parameterized :HEARTS)
```

Comment: So obvious, Dave. I'm embarrassed I forgot about this.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question a long while ago, not regarding enums but static class members in general: [How can I dynamically look up a static class member in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940425/how-can-i-dynamically-look-up-a-static-class-member-in-clojure)

The answer was to use Java reflection:

```
(defn do-something-parameterized [suit]
  (let [s (.get (.getField Suits suit) nil)] (...)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, you could create a map with the string that you want to match, to the enum type, for example:

```
 (def my-enum-map {"DIAMONDS" Suits/DIAMONDS, "SPADES" Suits/SPADES...})
```

Then in the do something function it would look like:

```
 (defn do-something-parameterized [suit]
    (let [s (my-enum-map suit)] ...))
```

And you can build this map during load time using reflection (instead of by hand), but during runtime, its just a map lookup.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defmacro def-enum-alias
  "Make name reference enum.

   (def-enum-alias enum-name MyClass$MyEnum)

   (enum-name Foo)

   second desugars to MyClass$MyEnum/Foo"
  [name enum]
  `(defmacro ~name
     ~(str "automatically generated alias for enum "
           enum)
     [member#]
     (symbol-munge (quote ~enum) "/" member#)))
```